# Deploy Mercure on Apache Server

Tags: apache, symfony, ssl, caddy, mercure

I'm having trouble setting up Mercure in production mode with Symfony 4.4 on ovh server. It's working well in dev mode but when I'm trying to deploy it in prod, I have this issue.

```
loading initial config: loading new config: http app module: start: tcp: listening on :443: listen tcp :443: bind: address already in use
```

Here's my Caddyfile

```
{
#       {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
}

{$SERVER_NAME:monsite.fr}

log

route {
        redir / /.well-known/mercure/ui/
        encode zstd gzip

        mercure {
                # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
                transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt://mercure.db}
                # Publisher JWT key
                publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
                # Subscriber JWT key
                subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
                # Permissive configuration for the development environment
                cors_origins *
                publish_origins *
                demo
                anonymous
                subscriptions
                # Extra directives
                {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
        }

        respond /healthz 200

        respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

So I tried to change the port with port 3000 but then I got this error :

```
2022/08/29 11:28:41.230 ERROR   tls.issuance.acme.acme_client   deactivating authorization  {"identifier": "monsite.fr", "authz": "https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/authz/BXGXc1Fhb2xL6WN4PNWyGw", "error": "request to https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/authz/BXGXc1Fhb2xL6WN4PNWyGw failed after 1 attempts: context canceled"}
2022/08/29 11:28:41.230 ERROR   tls.obtain  could not get certificate from issuer   {"identifier": "monsite.fr", "issuer": "acme.zerossl.com-v2-DV90", "error": "[monsite.fr] solving challenges: [monsite.fr] context canceled (order=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/order/Db-LeFrtzvBUllnxtuU8og) (ca=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90)"}
2022/08/29 11:28:41.230 INFO    tls.obtain  releasing lock  {"identifier": "monsite.fr"}
2022/08/29 11:28:41.230 ERROR   tls.obtain  unable to unlock    {"identifier": "monsite.fr", "lock_key": "issue_cert_monsite.fr", "error": "remove /root/.local/share/caddy/locks/issue_cert_monsite.fr.lock: no such file or directory"}
2022/08/29 11:28:41.230 ERROR   tls job failed  {"error": "monsite.fr: obtaining certificate: [monsite.fr] Obtain: [monsite.fr] solving challenges: [monsite.fr] context canceled (order=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/order/Db-LeFrtzvBUllnxtuU8og) (ca=https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90)"}
```

I have a Let's Encrypt certificate on the domain but I found on the web that changing the port doesn't work with Lets Encrypt.

But the port 80 and 443 are already in use, what can I do to make it work please ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this made it work :

Stop the program using the port 443, start the mercure server (it will get the certificate), restart the program that was using the port 443.

I am however not sure if certificate renewal will work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).